# Как программно в принтере "поменять" размер бумаги?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, принтер

..проект готов, приступаем к печати. Документы нужно разослать по принтерам. 
Самый минимум: большие - на плоттер, маленькие - на ближайший принтер (прога знает на какие, и какие нужны форматы бумаги).

```
// ставим принтер, скорее всего работает, не проверял, но видел работу в демках
Printer.PrinterIndex := 3;

Printer.Orientation := poLandscape; //проверено - работает

Printer.? PaperSize, PaperName ? -
```

как установить требуемый размер бумаги?

на крайний случай выбрать и установить из числа предопределённых форматов?

или нужно каждый раз выполнять дополнительно рутинную установку штатными диалогами?

распечатка простого примера: 1-Титульный А3ландшафт, 2-записка А4портрет, 3-отчет измерений А4л, 4-каталог А4п, 5-схема А4-А2пл, 6-план А4-А0лп, 7-акт А4п
7раз менять - 1 раз обязательно вручную, и это если схема и план А4. 
Особенно глупо это выглядит при печати в pdf.

Есть мысль дважды установить на клиентском компе принтер с разными дефолтными настройками бумаги например EPSON WF-7515 А4 и EPSON WF-7515 А3....

Answer (score 1):

Свойства PageHeight, PageWidth, PageNumber - только для чтения, поэтому, если желаем что-то поменять, придётся лезть через WinAPI (сразу даю [ссылку на размеры бумаги](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/paper-sizes)). У меня есть старый пример, в котором мне приходилось выводить наклейки для коллекции сразу на конверт:

```
var
  Device, Driver, Port: array[0..80] of char; // порылся с утра в справке, лучше 0..80, хотя у меня работало и 0..255
  handle: THandle;
  pDevmode: PDeviceMode;

<..>
  // код работал нормально только тогда, когда перед ним делал сброс:

  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, handle);
  Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, 0);

  // собственно работа с DevMode
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, handle);
  if handle <> 0 then
  begin
    pDevMode := GlobalLock(handle);
    if pDevmode <> nil then
    try
      with pDevmode^ do
      begin
        dmPapersize := DMPAPER_A5; // нужные размеры - по ссылке
        dmFields := dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE;
      end;
    finally
      GlobalUnlock(Devmode);
    end;
  end;
```

А вообще размеры можно менять произвольно, выставив `pDevMode^.dmFields:=pDevMode^.dmFields or DMBIN_MANUAL`

Comment: Большое Спасибо за единственный ответ на 2 форумах.

Comment: Это вторая часть ответа (установка произвольной бумаги), с которой я через месяц-два буду разбираться. Меня сразу расстроило отсутствие DMPAPER_A1 и DMPAPER_A0 по ссылке. Но хуже всего, что строка "uses Windows"  причинит мне много хлопот.

Comment: 1 часть ответа - Установка предопределённых форматов бумаги Printer.PapSize.PaperName:=PaperName; - работает, проверено! (в  lazarus)

Comment: подробнее http://freepascal.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=40084

Comment: @ОлегКрук А вы пробовали "DMPAPER_A1"? У меня съел, но у меня нет такого принтера :) И чем плохо использовать WinAPI?

Comment: @ОлегКрук Проверил "Printer.PapSize.PaperName:=PaperName". WinXP + HP 1320 работает. Win7 + он же сетевой - не работает, Win10 + Epson TX650 не работает. В обоих случаях неработы ошибка "Unsupported ESC command' - очень давно не видел такой ошибки :)

Comment: У нас принтера долго не живут, поэтому все новые, подключены в сеть сетевым кабелем. - всё норм. Я попросил коллегу дать сетевой доступ к нашему принтеру, затем установил его "по старинке" как сетевой - всё норм, напечатал на бумаге(которая плотностью 80) на разных форматах несколько страниц. - всё в порядке

Comment: Правда в процессе тестов 1 плоттер (подключенный через комп с 2 сетевухами к другой сети), при тотальной проверке всех форматов функцией из http://freepascal.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=40084 в 30% случаев выдавал разные ошибки на случайных форматах

Comment: У меня сейчас нет времени и подходящих условий с этим разбираться, если прогу запущу на 200 компов и 30 принтеров - само вылезет.  А  пока Win7-64, Epson WF-7515 Series (Сеть), 44-дюймовый HP Designjet T790ps HPGL2 - реальные, doPDF, Отправить в OneNote 2010 - виртуальные - полёт нормальный

Comment: чем плохо использовать WinAPI? - тут у нас сильный, приближающийся запах Андройдов-Люниксов. И я уже "набил шишку" об дельфийский TMetaFile ;(

Comment: Попробуйте после Printer.PapSize.PaperName:=PaperName воткнуть Sleep(1000);  или Application.ProcessMessages;  или оба сразу, а потом опрашивать...

Comment: @ОлегКрук Это, разумеется, пробовал, не зря же код немного хитро написан :) Нет, не в транзакции дело. А если уж отходить от WInAPI на запах других ОС, перемещайтесь на FMX, но там другой подход, будьте готовы мыслить в ppi, а не обычных представления размера бумаги

Answer (score 0):

Список размеров страниц:

```
type
  RPaperSize = packed record
    psWinPrnID: Byte; psName: string[33];
    psWidthMM, psHeightMM: Single;
  end;

const
  // Размеры страниц печати:
  WinPaperSizes: array[0..117] of RPaperSize = (
    (psWinPrnID:1; psName:'US Letter'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:2; psName:'US Letter Small'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:3; psName:'US Tabloid'; psWidthMM:279.4; psHeightMM:431.8),
    (psWinPrnID:4; psName:'US Ledger'; psWidthMM:431.8; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:5; psName:'US Legal'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:355.6),
    (psWinPrnID:6; psName:'US Statement'; psWidthMM:139.7; psHeightMM:215.9),
    (psWinPrnID:7; psName:'US Executive'; psWidthMM:184.15; psHeightMM:266.7),
    (psWinPrnID:8; psName:'A3'; psWidthMM:297; psHeightMM:420),
    (psWinPrnID:9; psName:'A4'; psWidthMM:210; psHeightMM:297),
    (psWinPrnID:10; psName:'A4 Small'; psWidthMM:210; psHeightMM:297),
    (psWinPrnID:11; psName:'A5'; psWidthMM:148; psHeightMM:210),
    (psWinPrnID:12; psName:'B4 (JIS)'; psWidthMM:257; psHeightMM:364),
    (psWinPrnID:13; psName:'B5 (JIS)'; psWidthMM:182; psHeightMM:257),
    (psWinPrnID:14; psName:'Folio'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:330.2),
    (psWinPrnID:15; psName:'Quarto'; psWidthMM:215; psHeightMM:275),
    (psWinPrnID:16; psName:'10X14'; psWidthMM:254; psHeightMM:355.6),
    (psWinPrnID:17; psName:'11X17'; psWidthMM:279.4; psHeightMM:431.8),
    (psWinPrnID:18; psName:'US Note'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:19; psName:'US Envelope #9'; psWidthMM:98.425; psHeightMM:225.425),
    (psWinPrnID:20; psName:'US Envelope #10'; psWidthMM:104.775; psHeightMM:241.3),
    (psWinPrnID:21; psName:'US Envelope #11'; psWidthMM:114.3; psHeightMM:263.525),
    (psWinPrnID:22; psName:'US Envelope #12'; psWidthMM:120.65; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:23; psName:'US Envelope #14'; psWidthMM:127; psHeightMM:292.1),

    (psWinPrnID:24; psName:'C size sheet'; psWidthMM:431.8; psHeightMM:558.8),
    (psWinPrnID:25; psName:'D size sheet'; psWidthMM:558.8; psHeightMM:863.6),
    (psWinPrnID:26; psName:'E size sheet'; psWidthMM:863.6; psHeightMM:1117.6),

    (psWinPrnID:27; psName:'Envelope DL'; psWidthMM:110; psHeightMM:220),
    (psWinPrnID:28; psName:'Envelope C5'; psWidthMM:162; psHeightMM:229),
    (psWinPrnID:29; psName:'Envelope C3'; psWidthMM:324; psHeightMM:458),
    (psWinPrnID:30; psName:'Envelope C4'; psWidthMM:229; psHeightMM:324),
    (psWinPrnID:31; psName:'Envelope C6'; psWidthMM:114; psHeightMM:162),
    (psWinPrnID:32; psName:'Envelope C65'; psWidthMM:114; psHeightMM:229),
    (psWinPrnID:33; psName:'Envelope B4'; psWidthMM:250; psHeightMM:353),
    (psWinPrnID:34; psName:'Envelope B5'; psWidthMM:176; psHeightMM:250),
    (psWinPrnID:35; psName:'Envelope B6'; psWidthMM:176; psHeightMM:125),
    (psWinPrnID:36; psName:'Envelope'; psWidthMM:110; psHeightMM:230),
    (psWinPrnID:37; psName:'US Envelope Monarch'; psWidthMM:98.425; psHeightMM:190.5),
    (psWinPrnID:38; psName:'6 3/4 US Envelope'; psWidthMM:92.075; psHeightMM:165.1),
    (psWinPrnID:39; psName:'US Std Fanfold'; psWidthMM:377.825; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:40; psName:'German Std Fanfold'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:304.8),
    (psWinPrnID:41; psName:'German Legal Fanfold'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:330.2),
    (psWinPrnID:42; psName:'B4 (ISO)'; psWidthMM:250; psHeightMM:353),
    (psWinPrnID:43; psName:'Japanese Postcard'; psWidthMM:100; psHeightMM:148),
    (psWinPrnID:44; psName:'9X11'; psWidthMM:228.6; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:45; psName:'10X11'; psWidthMM:254; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:46; psName:'15X11'; psWidthMM:381; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:47; psName:'Envelope Invite'; psWidthMM:220; psHeightMM:220),

    (psWinPrnID:48; psName:'RESERVED--DO NOT USE'; psWidthMM:0; psHeightMM:0),
    (psWinPrnID:49; psName:'RESERVED--DO NOT USE'; psWidthMM:0; psHeightMM:0),

    (psWinPrnID:50; psName:'US Letter Extra'; psWidthMM:241.3; psHeightMM:304.8),
    (psWinPrnID:51; psName:'US Legal Extra'; psWidthMM:241.3; psHeightMM:381),
    (psWinPrnID:52; psName:'US Tabloid Extra'; psWidthMM:296.926; psHeightMM:457.2),
    (psWinPrnID:53; psName:'A4 Extra'; psWidthMM:235.458; psHeightMM:322.326),
    (psWinPrnID:54; psName:'Letter Transverse'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:279.4),
    (psWinPrnID:55; psName:'A4 Transverse'; psWidthMM:210; psHeightMM:297),
    (psWinPrnID:56; psName:'Letter Extra Transverse'; psWidthMM:241.3; psHeightMM:304.8),
    (psWinPrnID:57; psName:'SuperA/SuperA/A4'; psWidthMM:227; psHeightMM:356),
    (psWinPrnID:58; psName:'SuperB/SuperB/A3'; psWidthMM:305; psHeightMM:487),
    (psWinPrnID:59; psName:'US Letter Plus'; psWidthMM:215.9; psHeightMM:322.326),
    (psWinPrnID:60; psName:'A4 Plus'; psWidthMM:210; psHeightMM:330),
    (psWinPrnID:61; psName:'A5 Transverse'; psWidthMM:148; psHeightMM:210),
    (psWinPrnID:62; psName:'B5 (JIS) Transverse'; psWidthMM:182; psHeightMM:257),
    (psWinPrnID:63; psName:'A3 Extra'; psWidthMM:322; psHeightMM:445),
    (psWinPrnID:64; psName:'A5 Extra'; psWidthMM:174; psHeightMM:235),
    (psWinPrnID:65; psName:'B5 (ISO) Extra'; psWidthMM:201; psHeightMM:276),
    (psWinPrnID:66; psName:'A2'; psWidthMM:420; psHeightMM:594),
    (psWinPrnID:67; psName:'A3 Transverse'; psWidthMM:297; psHeightMM:420),
    (psWinPrnID:68; psName:'A3 Extra Transverse'; psWidthMM:322; psHeightMM:445),
    (psWinPrnID:69; psName:'Japanese Double Postcard'; psWidthMM:200; psHeightMM:148),
    (psWinPrnID:70; psName:'A6'; psWidthMM:105; psHeightMM:148),

    (psWinPrnID:71; psName:'Japanese Envelope Kaku #2'; psWidthMM:240; psHeightMM:332),
    (psWinPrnID:72; psName:'Japanese Envelope Kaku #3'; psWidthMM:216; psHeightMM:277),
    (psWinPrnID:73; psName:'Japanese Envelope Chou #3'; psWidthMM:120; psHeightMM:235),
    (psWinPrnID:74; psName:'Japanese Envelope Chou #4'; psWidthMM:90; psHeightMM:205),

    (psWinPrnID:75; psName:'Letter Rotated'; psWidthMM:279.4; psHeightMM:215.9),
    (psWinPrnID:76; psName:'A3 Rotated'; psWidthMM:420; psHeightMM:297),
    (psWinPrnID:77; psName:'A4 Rotated'; psWidthMM:297; psHeightMM:210),
    (psWinPrnID:78; psName:'A5 Rotated'; psWidthMM:210; psHeightMM:148),
    (psWinPrnID:79; psName:'B4 (JIS) Rotated'; psWidthMM:364; psHeightMM:257),
    (psWinPrnID:80; psName:'B5 (JIS) Rotated'; psWidthMM:257; psHeightMM:182),
    (psWinPrnID:81; psName:'Japanese Postcard Rotated'; psWidthMM:148; psHeightMM:100),
    (psWinPrnID:82; psName:'Double Japanese Postcard Rotated'; psWidthMM:148; psHeightMM:200),
    (psWinPrnID:83; psName:'A6 Rotated'; psWidthMM:148; psHeightMM:105),

    (psWinPrnID:84; psName:'Japanese Envelope Kaku #2 Rotated'; psWidthMM:332; psHeightMM:240),
    (psWinPrnID:85; psName:'Japanese Envelope Kaku #3 Rotated'; psWidthMM:277; psHeightMM:216),
    (psWinPrnID:86; psName:'Japanese Envelope Chou #3 Rotated'; psWidthMM:235; psHeightMM:120),
    (psWinPrnID:87; psName:'Japanese Envelope Chou #4 Rotated'; psWidthMM:205; psHeightMM:90),

    (psWinPrnID:88; psName:'B6 (JIS)'; psWidthMM:128; psHeightMM:182),
    (psWinPrnID:89; psName:'B6 (JIS) Rotated'; psWidthMM:182; psHeightMM:128),
    (psWinPrnID:90; psName:'12X11'; psWidthMM:304.8; psHeightMM:279.4),

    (psWinPrnID:91; psName:'Japanese Envelope You #4'; psWidthMM:105; psHeightMM:235),
    (psWinPrnID:92; psName:'Japanese Envelope You #4 Rotated'; psWidthMM:235; psHeightMM:105),

    (psWinPrnID:93; psName:'PRC 16K'; psWidthMM:146; psHeightMM:215),
    (psWinPrnID:94; psName:'PRC 32K'; psWidthMM:97; psHeightMM:151),
    (psWinPrnID:95; psName:'PRC 32K(Big)'; psWidthMM:97; psHeightMM:151),
    (psWinPrnID:96; psName:'PRC Envelope #1'; psWidthMM:102; psHeightMM:165),
    (psWinPrnID:97; psName:'PRC Envelope #2'; psWidthMM:102; psHeightMM:176),
    (psWinPrnID:98; psName:'PRC Envelope #3'; psWidthMM:125; psHeightMM:176),
    (psWinPrnID:99; psName:'PRC Envelope #4'; psWidthMM:110; psHeightMM:208),
    (psWinPrnID:100; psName:'PRC Envelope #5'; psWidthMM:110; psHeightMM:220),
    (psWinPrnID:101; psName:'PRC Envelope #6'; psWidthMM:120; psHeightMM:230),
    (psWinPrnID:102; psName:'PRC Envelope #7'; psWidthMM:160; psHeightMM:230),
    (psWinPrnID:103; psName:'PRC Envelope #8'; psWidthMM:120; psHeightMM:309),
    (psWinPrnID:104; psName:'PRC Envelope #9'; psWidthMM:229; psHeightMM:324),
    (psWinPrnID:105; psName:'PRC Envelope #10'; psWidthMM:324; psHeightMM:458),
    (psWinPrnID:106; psName:'PRC 16K Rotated'; psWidthMM:215; psHeightMM:146),
    (psWinPrnID:107; psName:'PRC 32K Rotated'; psWidthMM:151; psHeightMM:97),
    (psWinPrnID:108; psName:'PRC 32K(Big) Rotated'; psWidthMM:151; psHeightMM:97),
    (psWinPrnID:109; psName:'PRC Envelope #1 Rotated'; psWidthMM:165; psHeightMM:102),
    (psWinPrnID:110; psName:'PRC Envelope #2 Rotated'; psWidthMM:176; psHeightMM:102),
    (psWinPrnID:111; psName:'PRC Envelope #3 Rotated'; psWidthMM:176; psHeightMM:125),
    (psWinPrnID:112; psName:'PRC Envelope #4 Rotated'; psWidthMM:208; psHeightMM:110),
    (psWinPrnID:113; psName:'PRC Envelope #5 Rotated'; psWidthMM:220; psHeightMM:110),
    (psWinPrnID:114; psName:'PRC Envelope #6 Rotated'; psWidthMM:230; psHeightMM:120),
    (psWinPrnID:115; psName:'PRC Envelope #7 Rotated'; psWidthMM:230; psHeightMM:160),
    (psWinPrnID:116; psName:'PRC Envelope #8 Rotated'; psWidthMM:309; psHeightMM:120),
    (psWinPrnID:117; psName:'PRC Envelope #9 Rotated'; psWidthMM:324; psHeightMM:229),
    (psWinPrnID:118; psName:'PRC Envelope #10 Rotated'; psWidthMM:458; psHeightMM:324)
  );
```

Comment: а это точно является ответом на заданный вопрос?

Comment: нет, это дополнение к выше приведённому коду, вместо ссылки на размеры страниц., непосредственно туда ответить не могу, не хватает репутации.

Comment: думаю, лучше будет нажать [edit] и предварить ваш ответ уведомлением, что это не ответ, а дополнение к другому ответу, и применять ваше предложение следует так-то и так-то.